# How to publish war and jar-classes artifacts in Gradle

Tags: gradle

In Maven is super easy; just add one line

```
<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
```

and two artifacts goes to repository ([doc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#attachClasses))

My build.gradle is:

```
group = 'org.gradle.sample'
version = '1.0'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
jar.enabled = true
jar.classifier = 'classes'

repositories {
   mavenLocal()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        p1(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
        p2(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:3.6.7.Final'
}
```

Command:  `gradle jar publishToMavenLocal`

Similar to Maven, 2 artifacts goes to repository (publish-1.0.war and publish-1.0-classes.jar) Moreover, publish-1.0.pom goes to repository but without dependencies. Finally, dependency to Hibernate is lost

For example, I created other Maven project which depends on `publish`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.gradle.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>publish</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

but there is no dependency to hibernate:

> [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my-app ---
>
> [INFO] com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>
> [INFO] - org.gradle.sample:publish:jar:classes:1.0:compile
>
> [INFO] (I expect hibernate with it's dependencies but there is not)
>
> ---

Why Gradle is not as smart as Maven is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found pitiful solution: swap publishing order

```
publishing {
    publications {
        p1(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
        p2(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```